# Get string from url in config() method?

Tags: angularjs

I use angularjs 1.5.

in `module.config()` I need to from part from url.

for example:

```
www.portalName.com/applicationName#/MainPage
```

I need get this:

```
applicationName
```

I tried to use $location service but service is unavailable in config().

Any idea how can I get `applicationName` from URL in config() method?

Comment: Have you tried reading from $state's service params field? `$state.params`

Comment: Which routing solution are you using? ngRoute or ui-router?

Comment: only providers and constants can be injected into configuration phase ,so that they wont get instantiated before the service is fully configured as it is configuration phase

Comment: @timenomad I use ui-router